# Execute a python file using subprocess in a flask app rather than writing the script inside the flask app

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I would like to get your thoughts about this approach of using subprocess and flask.

In my flask app I have this function:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    dump_cmd = 'python3 file.py'
    p = subprocess.Popen(dump_cmd, shell=True)
    return 'seccess'
```

What I'm trying to do is to prevent stoping and starting the flask app each time I modify the script, so what I did is to write all the script in another file and execute it using subprocess. I would like to know if this is a good way of doing things or should I write the code inside the flask app ? Does this have an impact of time execution ?

Comment: Can't provide any evidence why I think this is not a great solution but I'm curious to know how you think you can debug file.py code using this setup?

Comment: The work done in file.py is for statistic purpose and it's in the back-end, so I don't want to show the user errors or any messages. Besides, I don't want the app to stop if an error occured in file.py. For the debug, I can use 'nohup' and write the outputs to a log file for example.

Comment: This might sound silly but if you have a python script that you want to call and make sure the user does not see the output, why would you use flask in the first place? If you want the user to trigger the starting of this ability I think you would be better off using something like asyncio, so you can always provide correct input to the user and the script will be run in parallel somewhere else. Optionally you could use a queue manager (rabbitmq or similar) to achieve this.

Comment: First, I didn't said that I'm using flask only to acheive this. I have a complete API running with flask, It does more stuff. The function that I presented here is just an example. Second, the user does send inputs to the server, and I'm using ajax to call the function, but I don't want to return anything. Finally, I didn't ask if It's silly in the opinion of others, I just want to know If it has an impact on the execution time or not.

Comment: You sound a bit hostile and I'm only trying to answer your questions. You literally ask the question "I would like to know if this is a good way of doing things or should I write the code inside the flask app ?" to which my response was the explanation above. I don't know if it impacts execution time, but someone else might.